# JDBC executeUpdate vs executeBatch Performance

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I am curious to know the performance difference between JDBC executeUpdate(multiQuerySqlString) vs JDBC executeBatch() in executing multiple update/insert queries.

For example:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(updateQuery1+";");
sb.append(updateQuery2+";");
sb.append(insertQuery1+";");
statement.executeUpdate(sb.toString())
```

vs

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateQuery1);
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateQuery2);
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery1);
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: You use batch incorrectly, it will only execute the last query this way. And `;` separated statements are technically not allowed by JDBC (although some drivers do support it).

Answer (score 3):

It is *likely* that a batch will be faster than a sequence of `executeUpdate` (etc) statements because batching reduces the number of Java <-> database round-trips, and may make other optimizations possible.

However, the actual performance difference will depend on the JDBC driver and the back-end database you are using.

The only way to get an answer that is applicable to your (hypothetical) use-case is to benchmark the two alternative ways of implementing the operations with your actual database, driver, SQL and datasets.

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems in your example:

1. Multiquery string is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work?noredirect=1&lq=1), because you will manipulate the query by your self.
2. Your batch update is wrong. You are reasigning the variable prepared statement. See how to use correctly here: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/

Example of BatchInsert:

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);//commit trasaction manually

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong101");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
preparedStatement.addBatch();

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 102);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong102");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.executeBatch();

dbConnection.commit();
```